# Is there a way to dynamically choose a table in a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say there is a table named `Card(id, type)` and tables

```
CardOneElement(card_id, element_id, field)
CardTwoElement(card_id, element_id, field)
CardThreeElement(card_id, element_id, field)
```

I want to write an SQL query that returns all elements for a card with card.type referencing one of the tables above. So something like

```sql
SELECT el.field FROM **TABLE_FOR(card.type)** AS el, Card AS card WHERE card.id=el.card_id;
```

I could probably write a `switch` statement with explicit queries for each table but would like to have a more elegant solution without writing additional queries for every table I'll create later.

Comment: The three tables should only be one to begin with and have a column named `card_type`

Comment: SQL doesn't support dynamic selection of table.  The problem is solved by combining all tables into a larger one with the addition of a 'table' identifier column.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dcfec5a335a6005d263bcdd98348f36e - if you have no choice